# Want to evaluate the polynomial equation

Tags: c#

In this case,this is the array which serves as coefficients and degrees which first value having no degree.

```
double[] arr = { 12, 2, 3 ,4};
```

I then made a method to print the above array in terms of polynomial equation.
It gives output in type string as follows :

```
2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + 12
```

I want to a function which takes an argument x and then solve the above polynomial with respect to value of x.
How can I do that?
Any kind of help will be appreciated!.

Edit: Question Solved

Comment: Have you ever tried to use a third part libraries like https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/LinearEquations.html ?

Comment: I am not that familiar with these libraries as I am new to c#

Comment: You mean 'evaluate' the polynomial, not 'solve' it for `==0` right?

Comment: Yes,putting in the value of x and calculating the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I created:

```
for (int i = 1; i < degree.Length; i++)
        {
            result_first += degree[i] * Math.Pow(x, degree[i]);
        }
        result_first += degree[0];
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate it you can simply sum the power values times the coefficients. Using LINQ, that's one line:

```
double result = arr.Select((c,i) => c * Math.Pow(x, i)).Sum();
```

Here `i` is the index into your array, it starts at zero, so `x^0 = 1 * 12 == 12` etc.

You can also do it without LINQ like this:

```
    List<string> debug = new List<string>();
    double y = 1.0;
    result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        debug.Add($"{arr[i]} * x^{i}"); 
        result = result + arr[i] * y;
        y = y * x;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" + ", debug));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which, for x=3 outputs:

```
  12 * x^0 + 2 * x^1 + 3 * x^2 + 4 * x^3
  153
```

Same result as LINQ.

Comment: Instead of 116,it gives me 17

Comment: @SibtainReza Check your input array, if you want 0 for x^1 you will need to include that in the array. It can't know that you have a missing coefficient.